# removeEventListener in object literal

Tags: javascript, object-literal, removeeventlistener

I'm struggling with `removeEventListener` in an object literal.
I have an object which deals with adding and removing custom outlines when the user is tabbing through a website.

```
const OUTLINE = {
  enableOutline: function () {
    if (event.key === 'Tab' || (event.shiftKey && event.key === 'Tab')) {
      document.addEventListener('focusin', () => this.showOutline());
    }
  },
  showOutline: function () {
    this.showLogoOutline(event);
  },
  showLogoOutline: function () {
    if (event.target === this.logo) {
      this.logo.classList.add('logo_outline');
    }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', () => OUTLINE.enableOutline(event));
```

The same object contains method which removes outline and unsuccesfully tries to remove the `EventListener`.

```
const OUTLINE = {
  hideOutline: function () {
    this.hideLogoOutline();
    // BELOW DOESN'T WORK
    document.removeEventListener('focusin', this.showOutline);
  },
  hideLogoOutline: function () {
    if (this.logo.classList.contains('logo_outline')) {
      this.logo.classList.remove('logo_outline');
    }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => OUTLINE.hideOutline());
```

Comment: That's because you're not removing the listener you added. The function `() => OUTLINE.hideOutline()` is _not_ the function `this.hideOutline()`; there's no searching or matching of any kind, it has to be _exactly_ the same thing.

Comment: I think you can not remove an anonymous eventlistener function anyways. At least you should have taken a reference for each by assigning them to corresponding variables. Had DOM API returned and UUID per added eventlistener you might use it as a reference but sadly that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: **never overload the tab key** (or any key with universal behaviour across all browsers). `Tab` is used by the browser to navigate through tabIndexable elements, and code like this "traps" the tab key. Not cool. Especially not for people who can't use a mouse. *Especially* if this is "just for you" or "just for [people who you know don't fall in that category]", *be in the habit of not overloading built-in behaviour* because that way you'll never write bad code when it *does* matter.

Having said that, you're not actually removing the listener you added. The function `() => OUTLINE.hideOutline()` is a new function, scoped to the declaration context (as opposed to execution context that you'd get if you used `function() { ...}`), and so points to a completely different thing than `OUTLINE.hideOutline` points to.

There's no searching or matching of any kind when removing listeners, it can only remove [exactly the same thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) that you told it to add earlier (i.e. it has to have same event name, the same function handle, and the same priority flag if you specified one).

Since this is a singleton object primitive (e.g. there is no meaningful `this`), don't use `this`, directly refer to itself using its `const` name, so you can add and remove its function through direct reference:

```
const OUTLINE = {
  ...
  enableOutline: function(event) {
    const { key } = event;
    if (key.toLowerCase() === `f`) {
      document.addEventListener('focusin', OUTLINE.showOutline);
    }
  }
  hideOutline: function(_event) {
    document.removeEventListener('focusin', OUTLINE.showOutline);
  },
};
```

But of course if you're going to have a setup where you need to add and remove event listeners a lot, write a simple event manager. E.g. start with something like this and customize it as needed.

```
class EventManager {
  constructor() {
    this.events = {};
  }

  listen(target, evtName, handler) {
    if (!this.events[evtName]) this.events[evtName] = [];

    const evtList= this.events[evtName];
    const position = this.events[evtName].length;
    const entry = { target, handler, removed:false, remove: () => {
      // removeEventListener always returns undefined
      evtList[position] = target.removeEventListener(evtName, handler);
      entry.removed = true;
    }});

    target.addEventListener(evtName, handler);
    this.events[evtName].push(entry);
    return entry;
  }

  forget(target, evtName, handler=false) {
    const evtList = this.events[evtName];
    evtList
      .filter(e => (e.target===target && (handler ? e.handler===handler : true)))
      .forEach(e => e.remove())
  }
}

const Events = new EventManager();

export default Events
```

which would turn your code into something like this:

```
import Events from "globalManager";

const OUTLINE = {
  ...
  enableOutline: function(event) {
    const { key } = event;
    if (key.toLowerCase() === `f` && !OUTLINE.listener) {
      OUTLINE.listener = Events.listen(document, `focusin`, OUTLINE.showOutline);
    }
  }
  hideOutline: function() {
    if (OUTLINE.listener) {
      OUTLINE.listener = OUTLINE.listener.remove();
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Using direct reference to the `const` instead of `this` fixed the issue. Thank you for your explanation and code examples. By the way, I didn't explain what the code is actually doing, so I think there was a misunderstanding (unless I'm missing something). `showLogoOutline()` is just one function from many I use to add custom outlines to all elements on the website. It is precisely for keyboard users.

Comment: Hmm, why? That's what the CSS `:focus` pseudo-selector is for? No need for JS for adding visual highlighting/outlines to elements when keyboard users tab to them.

Comment: You are right. I took a different approach and instead of adding and removing quintillion classes with different outlines using JS, I put them directly in the HTML document. Then, I'm adding one class which sets outline to none when the user is clicking and then I'm removing that same class when the user is tabbing. I have saved a significant pile of lines of code.  Thank you very, very much for all your help.

Comment: The whole point of CSS is that it _cascades_. You don't set a million classes, you set `*:focus { ... }` and now every element gets outline CSS applied. Also, I assume if you have a million elements, those are all JS-managed, you're not actually writing HTML with millions of elements, so make the JS add the necessary classes _when they construct them_ and you're done if you need a restricted set? Nothing complicated or time consuming about that. That said, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) in the comments, every time you say `() => aFunction()`, you're creating a completely new function. Just pass in the raw function like `aFunction`.

It also appears that you're not passing the `event` variable correctly, I've fixed that too in the codeblock below.

```js
const OUTLINE = {
  enableOutline: function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Tab' || (event.shiftKey && event.key === 'Tab')) {
      document.addEventListener('focusin', this.showOutline);
    }
  },
  showOutline: function (event) {
    this.showLogoOutline(event);
  },
  showLogoOutline: function (event) {
    if (event.target === this.logo) {
      this.logo.classList.add('logo_outline');
    }
  },
  hideOutline: function () {
    this.hideLogoOutline();
    document.removeEventListener('focusin', this.showOutline);
  },
  hideLogoOutline: function () {
    if (this.logo.classList.contains('logo_outline')) {
      this.logo.classList.remove('logo_outline');
    }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', OUTLINE.enableOutline);

document.addEventListener('mousedown', OUTLINE.hideOutline);
```